# change color on focus on blur on change

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to control the colors of a long form. I want the input color change on focus (already done) and on blur only if the user has made a change. Is it possible?

I have the example here to play: http://jsfiddle.net/pEqvK/

```
$(function(){

    $('input').css("color", "grey"); //initial value

    $("input").focus(function () {
        $(this).css("color", "black");
    });

    $("input").blur(function () {
        // if it changed $(this).css("color", "black");                   
        // if it nas NOT changed $(this).css("color", "grey");
    });

});
```

Comment: Store the value of the field temporarily when focus is on the element and then compare this against the value when the blur event is called. So for your focus function store the field value in a variable. In the blur function, compare it against the temp value.

Comment: You can use the `data-` attributes to store data in a tag directly, rather than using an external variable. My answer should provide a nice example. In the end it's a matter of taste really :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving what I believe you are trying to achieve, I would use some deeper semantic attributes on the tag, to specify the default value and then use that as a comparison:

HTML:

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" value="name" data-default="name" />
    <input type="text" value="mail" data-default="mail" />
</form>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){

    $('input').css("color", "grey"); //initial value

    $("input").focus(function () {
        $(this).css("color", "black"); // or "red" if I understood correctly what you want to do
    });

    $("input").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != $(this).data('default'))     
            $(this).css("color", "black");   
        else                
            $(this).css("color", "grey");
    });   
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pEqvK/8/

Answer (score 2):

Have a boolean variable named  `haschanged` be set to false on focus, set to true on change, and checked for truth on blur.

```
$(function(){
    var haschanged = false;  //stores changed state since focus

    $('input').css("color", "grey"); //initial value

    $("input").focus(function () {
        haschanged = false;
        $(this).css("color", "black");
    });

    $("input").change(function () {
        haschanged = true;
    });

    $("input").blur(function () {
        if(haschanged) $(this).css("color", "black");                   
        else           $(this).css("color", "grey");
    });

});
```

Comment: This would work yes. Kind of similar to my idea only better as you don't need to store the value of the field :)

Comment: This is a good solution. I have learned something new. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why are the other answers so complicated? (unless im missing something here) Try one line:

```
$("input").change(function() { $(this).css("color", "black"); // or set some boolean }
```

is this not the function your looking for? it is only called when there is a change, otherwise nothing is called. So you would want to default the color to grey first.

Comment: Would this event not fire each time a character was typed?

Comment: but there is a way to do that, hey, its still a change! Ya, gotta love  one line solutions!!!

Comment: This is a good solution but the problem is that "I want the input color change on focus"

Comment: this code is to be added instead of your `blur` function call. You will still need your lines above `blur`

Comment: Indeed, from the question this seems to work, but I believe that the OP actually wants to show as "colored" input with focus and as "grey" an input which has never been modified from its original value (so also modified once and then reverted, I believe)

Comment: Narcís - you have the same color in the change and focus events on your js fiddle. It works if you change the `black` to `grey` in the change event.

Comment: No, @Narcís and Tallmaris are right. Even with the color change you mentioned, it will color the input black by the focus event, which doesnt revert itself when you lose focus. So it stays black. Tallmaris' solution is a nice way to prevent that.

Comment: I tried what you say here: http://jsfiddle.net/pEqvK/9/ If there is no change in the text the color on blur changes and it should be the same.

Comment: Ok I see what you guys mean. Sorry, I'm half-sleeping today -_-

Answer (score 1):

The following will save the previous value to your input's data then look for and compare that value upon blur.  It also makes use of jQuery's chaining ability. You don't have to recall input everytime.

### jsFiddle

```
$('input').css("color", "grey")
    .focus(function () {
        $(this).css("color", "black")
            .data("prevValue", $(this).val());
    })
    .blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).data("prevValue")) $(this).css("color", "grey");
    });
```

> **HOWEVER** If you want something more like the forms you see on other sites, you might try the following:

```
$(function(){
    $('input').css("color", "grey")
        .each(function(i) { $(this).data("baseValue", $(this).val()) })
        .focus(function(e) {
            $(this).css("color", "black");
            if ($(this).val() == $(this).data("baseValue")) $(this).val("");
        })
        .blur(function(e) {
            if ($(this).val() == "") $(this).css("color", "grey").val($(this).data("baseValue"));
        });
})
```

### jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/pEqvK/5/

JS

```
$(function(){

    $('input').css("color", "grey"); //initial value

    var t1;
    var t2;

    $("input").focus(function () {
        t1 = $('#t1').val();
        t2 = $('#t2').val();
        $(this).css("color", "black");
      }).blur(function () {
        // if it changed $(this).css("color", "black");                      
        // if it nas NOT changed $(this).css("color", "grey");
        if($(this).attr('id')=='t1'&&$('#t1').val()==t1) {
            $(this).css("color", "grey");
        }
        if($(this).attr('id')=='t2'&&$('#t2').val()==t2) {
            $(this).css("color", "grey");
        }
      });

});​
```